# Searching for advices to understand why a jQuery click() function is triggered many times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, debugging, events, click

I've got a page on a website with a *users profiles validation panel* that a super-user must *validate manually* by clicking on *buttons* (that are HTML spans).

I use the `click()` jQuery function on the spans to catch the events. First time, the click appends normally. On second click it is triggered twice, on third click it runs 3 times, etc.

Here is some code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('span.button-validate').unbind("click").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log("click"); // This is logged 1, then 2, then 3, etc. 

        // complex code here, including AJAX...

    });
});
```

I've fixed any problem like JS errors or 404 files.

I use jQuery 1.7.2 and jQueryUI 1.8.21.

Can't reproduce the problem from this much-more-simple-than-reality example as @CKGrafico has showed with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5c2K/). Will improve it soon.

Comment: What is your ajax code doing? That's where I'd check first.

Comment: Have you tried splitting execution unbind and bind? I'm not sure if you can chain it.

Comment: @Jasen the ajax transmits an uri through the `load` function and it triggers a JSP page that return a status

Comment: @semao I've tried many things like the following examples : `$("#target").click(function {});` or `$("#target").on("click", function {});`. Is it what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give me more info? I can't see any problems in jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('span').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log("click"); // This is logged 1, then 2, then 3, etc. 

        // complex code here, including AJAX...

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v5c2K/

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Don't know how to simplify the complexity of the code. I'm gonna improve the fiddle soon.

Comment: The problem were coming from a bad using of nested `$(document).ready()` of the hell. Sorry.